# spectral projections

Tags: operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a von Neumann algebra, and $T$ be an hermitian element of $A$.  Show that the spectral projections of $ T $ belong to $A$.

Proof:  the spectral projections of $ T $ commute with every operator that commutes with $T$. so the spectral projections of $ T $ belong to $A$.

My question: Why do the spectral projections of $ T $ commute with every operator that commutes with $T$ and conversely ?

Comment: How do you define the spectral projections of $T$?

Comment: Check out Rudin's functional analysis book, page 324 (the proof of theorem 12.22 (e)).